# Why am I getting a 'Segmentation Fault: 11' line in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm new to coding in c++ and for a homework assignment I keep getting a Segmentation Fault: 11 and I'm not sure why. I did a little research beforehand and I tried changing all my variable names, with no difference. What should I do to fix this? Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string middle(string str);

string middle(string str){
    if(str.length() % 2 == 1){
        cout << str[str.length()/2] << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(str.length() % 2 == 0){
        cout << str[(str.length() + 1)/2];
        cout << str[((str.length() + 1)/2) - 1];
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    string a_word;

    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    cin >> a_word;
    middle(a_word);
}
```

Comment: You should have a check for string length zero written out

Comment: whats this supposed to do, find the middle letter of a word?

Comment: It appears your middle() function is supposed to be returning a string and not an integer. That might be part of your problem.

Comment: @churill Unfortunately that will compile... it uses constructor #5 in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string taking a `const char*`.

Comment: @Kevin Ugghh, you'r right and I guess you found the segfault, maybe.

Comment: @mashroor if i am able to solve your doubt please accept it as an answer by clicking on tick mark against my answer, so that others may also get benefited.

Comment: I upvoted this question because I don't believe its at all obvious to a new person why this is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void middle(string str){
    if(str.length() % 2 == 1){
        cout << str[str.length()/2] << endl;
        return ;
    }
    else if(str.length() % 2 == 0){
        cout << str[(str.length() + 1)/2];
        cout << str[((str.length() + 1)/2) - 1];
        return ;
    }
    return ;
}

int main(){
    string a_word;

    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    cin >> a_word;
    middle(a_word);
}
```

change your code to this it will work.
I have changed return type of function to void instead of string.
The segmentation fault occurs because you were returning an integer while return type of function was string.

Comment: If this is the actual code all the returns can be removed because no additional statements are executed after the if () {} else {}

Comment: It crashes because `0` is converted to a `nullptr` and the `std::string()` constructor that accepts a `const char*` is used. When the `nullptr` is dereferenced you will have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
string middle(string str)
```

defines a function that will return a `std::string`, but you do

```
return 0;
```

As Kevin correctly found out, this actually compiles. `std::string` has a constructor that takes only a `const char*` as parameter, thus it qualifies as implicit conversion constructor and the literal `0` can be parsed as a null pointer literal (doesn't work with other numbers). So the appropriate constructor ([number 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)) get's called and expects a valid pointer. The reference states that:

> The behavior is undefined if [s, s + Traits::length(s)) is not a valid range (for example, if s is a null pointer).

And exactly that's the case, the parameter passed to the constructor is `0`, so you get undefined behaviour. A seg fault in your case, an exception in my case.

---

To solve this, just remove all the `return`'s and change the return type to `void` since you neither use the returned value, not return any meaningfull value in the first place.

Note that this will still fail for empty strings, you should add a check for this case.

```
void middle(string str) {
    if(str.empty()) {
        return;
    }

    if (str.length() % 2 == 1) {
        cout << str[str.length()/2] << endl;
    }
    else if (str.length() % 2 == 0) {
        cout << str[(str.length() + 1)/2];
        cout << str[((str.length() + 1)/2) - 1];
    }
}
```